# Compiling revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, revealing-module-pattern

I'm writing an app that is using a revealing-ish module pattern. I'm using Gulp for compilation, so I can set the order of compilation. Aside from some jQuery, there aren't any other frameworks or libraries at play.

I'm trying to break the files up:

- The site's main JS file,
- one for a respective feature's general settings,
- one for the feature's UI,
- and another for the feature's data.

I'm trying to namespace as follows:

```
myApp
myApp.dashboard
myApp.dashboard.ui
myApp.dashboard.data
```

The problem is the namespace nesting because (for example) my `dashboard.ui.js` file is referenced in `dashboard.js`

I receive 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ui' of undefined` when it tries to access the `myApp.dashboard.ui`.

I've tried every order of compilation I can think of. I'm guessing there's something wrong with my pattern but I'm not sure what. Here's an example of the code.

// app.js

```
let myApp = (function(){

    const $els = {
        menu: $('#menu')
        // etc.
    };

    const eventHandlers = () => {
        //site-wide click event handlers (for example)
    };

    const utils = {
        // utility functions
    };

    const init = () => {
        // set some site variables, etc.
        eventHandlers();
    };

    return {
        init,
        utils
    };
})(myApp || {});
```

//dashboard.js

```
myApp.dashboard = (function (parent){

    // ! need access to the UI
    let ui = parent.dashboard.ui;

    const eventHandlers = () => {
        ...
    };

    const init = () => {
        eventHandlers();
    };

    return {
        init
    };

})(myApp || {});
```

//dashboard.ui.js

```
myApp.dashboard.ui = (function (parent){

    // ! need access to the DATA
    let ui = parent.dashboard.data;

    const htmlTemplate = (content) => {
        return `<h1>${content}</h1>`;
    };

    const setValidationFlags = () => {
        ...
    };

    return {
        setValidationFlags
    };

})(myApp || {});
```

//dashboard.data.js

```
myApp.dashboard.data = (function (parent){

    const getData = (dataObject) => {
        // do XHR look up
        // call setter, etc.
    };

    const parseForm = () => {
        // collect form data.
    };

    return {
        parseForm
    };

})(myApp || {});
```

Can someone please provide some guidance on how to correct my code so that I can nest the UI and Data portions under the `myApp.dashboard` namespace and have the three accessible to one another?

If this pattern is way off base, pointers on how to improve it are also welcome.

Comment: using IIFEs is the issue. all the code should be loaded before its executed, I would extend the myApp to have a dynamic getter which invokes the arbitrary child object as you traverse it, rather then invoke everything as its seen.

Answer (score 0):

`dashboard` requires `ui` requires `data`, so you need to load them in the reverse order. And have each module set up the whole namespace tree it needs when it is not yet available:

```
// data.js
var myApp;
if (!myApp) myApp = {};
if (!myApp.dashboard) myApp.dashboard = {};
myApp.dashboard.data = (function(){
    …
    return { parseForm };
})();

// ui.js
var myApp;
if (!myApp) myApp = {};
if (!myApp.dashboard) myApp.dashboard = {};
myApp.dashboard.ui = (function(){
    // need access to the DATA
    const data = myApp.dashboard.data;
    …
    return {setValidationFlags};
})();

// dashboard.js
var myApp;
if (!myApp) myApp = {};
if (!myApp.dashboard) myApp.dashboard = {};
myApp.dashboard.init = (function(){
    // need access to the UI
    const ui = parent.dashboard.ui;
    …
    return () => {
        eventHandlers();
    };
})();
```

The alternative would be not to use references to the other modules inside the IIFE that is executed immediately, but to defer them until the `init` call which is when all modules should have been loaded.

Comment: Bergi, would you be willing to share a code example of your alternative suggestion?